# Missing something with understanding promises for linear code processes?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to understand the benefit of promises in NodeJS while working on a re-write of some code.  We are attempting to rewrite some legacy functions with NodeJS, but it seems like I would have

The first action is to get the Account Value (however this function to get the account details returns a promise), and most of the subsequent functions that follow also similarly return promises also, so do I have to nest a bunch of .then(()=>{ }) statements into a function that basically ends up looking like this:

```
getAcct().then((account) => {
    // with account update funds...
    account.updateFunds().then((newAcct) => {
        // with newAcct update the value...
        newAcct().updateVal().then((update) => {
            ....... And continue down the same nested .then() path???
        }
    }
}
```

I basically have a lot of code that has to have data from subsequent code that runs before it (for example: I need to get the account value before I do any thing, and I need that value to determine the next logic, and that next logic will need details from additional methods that need to also resolve promises before moving forward.

Ideally, I would think that I could assign the value from the first promise into a variable and then use it when it is resolved for the next action(s) that need to take place that use the value.

Coming from a C# (.NET) background so having difficultly understanding how to use the promises with NodeJS.  But I wouldn't think that nesting them continually infinitely deep would be the correct way to accomplish, so thought I would look for some advice to help.

Any advise is appreciated.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) your promise and store the result in a variable.

```
const account = await getAcct();
```

You will need to run your await inside of an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and the await keyword will instruct the function to pause execution until the promise has resolved.

Comment: Is that the best practice for this type of processing?  Or is there other intended patterns and best practices for accomplishing inline dependent data processing with nodeJS?

Comment: This is a natively supported pattern in node.js, but there are non-native libraries that handle async differently. It depends on what you're trying to do, ideally you'd let your promises resolve in parallel with Promise.all, but in your case you can't do that.